# Does display flex takes element out of the document flow?

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I have a div with two child div and each of them has an svg icon inside of it, this is the HTML I have and the corresponding CSS:

```css
.gallery-nav {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.gallery-nav div {
        background-color: yellow;
        //width: 50%;
    }

#white-bg {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-nav">
                <div>
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
                    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
                    <svg
                        version="1.1"
                        id="Layer_1"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                        x="0px"
                        y="0px"
                        viewBox="0 0 492.004 492.004"
                        style="enable-background: new 0 0 492.004 492.004"
                        xml:space="preserve"
                    >
                        <g>
                            <g>
                                <path
                                    d="M382.678,226.804L163.73,7.86C158.666,2.792,151.906,0,144.698,0s-13.968,2.792-19.032,7.86l-16.124,16.12
            c-10.492,10.504-10.492,27.576,0,38.064L293.398,245.9l-184.06,184.06c-5.064,5.068-7.86,11.824-7.86,19.028
            c0,7.212,2.796,13.968,7.86,19.04l16.124,16.116c5.068,5.068,11.824,7.86,19.032,7.86s13.968-2.792,19.032-7.86L382.678,265
            c5.076-5.084,7.864-11.872,7.848-19.088C390.542,238.668,387.754,231.884,382.678,226.804z"
                                />
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </div>
                <div id="white-bg">
                    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
                    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
                    <svg
                        version="1.1"
                        id="Layer_1"
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                        x="0px"
                        y="0px"
                        viewBox="0 0 492.004 492.004"
                        style="enable-background: new 0 0 492.004 492.004"
                        xml:space="preserve"
                    >
                        <g>
                            <g>
                                <path
                                    d="M382.678,226.804L163.73,7.86C158.666,2.792,151.906,0,144.698,0s-13.968,2.792-19.032,7.86l-16.124,16.12
            c-10.492,10.504-10.492,27.576,0,38.064L293.398,245.9l-184.06,184.06c-5.064,5.068-7.86,11.824-7.86,19.028
            c0,7.212,2.796,13.968,7.86,19.04l16.124,16.116c5.068,5.068,11.824,7.86,19.032,7.86s13.968-2.792,19.032-7.86L382.678,265
            c5.076-5.084,7.864-11.872,7.848-19.088C390.542,238.668,387.754,231.884,382.678,226.804z"
                                />
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </div>
```

When I apply the a flex display on the div with the gallery-nav class both icons disappear and the only to make them appear again is by giving them both a width.
why is that? does flex take these element from the document flow or is this some sort of an SVG related behavior.

Comment: They don't disappear, just look at your snippet above. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: The divs are collapsed to 0, so yes, you will need to geive them a width. In flex boxes you can use something like `flex:0 0 50%;` - the abrevited declaration for   `flex-grow [flex-shrink] [flex-basis];` Alternatively you can use only `flex-basis: 50%`

Comment: The `<svg>` and `<div>` elements are collapsing to size 0x0 because you aren't giving the browser any hint as to what size they ought to be.  The SVGs are trying to size themselves to their container divs. And the divs need to know the content sizes in order to work out how much of the flex row they should take up.

Comment: @johannes - What browser are you checking in? They disappear in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: @enxaneta so they are as if being take out of the document flow because the .gallery-nav  has height and width and the svgs inside should take all space within their parent element.

Comment: @Alohci I used Firefox

Comment: @PaulLeBeau But the parent div with .gallery-nav  has a height and width

Answer (score 0):

```
.gallery-nav div svg {
    width: 100%;
}
```

would you try this?

Comment: .gallery-nav div  {
    width: 100%;
}

Just adding this fixes it but I want to know why this behavior is happening

Comment: You need to size the svg element not parent

Comment: if you give the parent a width the svg inside will automatically take 100%. do you have an idea why this behavior is happening?